# Use OpenNTF Domino API without server install?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Want to use the OpenNTF Domino API for a XPages web application, but where I work I'm not allowed to have anything installed on the Domino servers.

Is it possible to use the OpenNTF Domino API for a browser xpages application without the server side install?  Can it be loaded in the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: Only a much older version of it would be available, and that's a PITA.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the update site way to deploy extensions. You put the update site database on your server, add a notes.ini variable and then add the projects (Ext Lib, OpenNTF API, etc) to the update site. They get deployed to the server with no need to copy files. Many customers allow this but don't allow copying files to the server.

Comment: Will run this past the administration team.  Issue is around adding non-IBM code to servers.  Have to prove it is not evil ;)

Comment: Any code you and your team write is not "IBM" code!

Comment: ... and perhaps another point is that it will not "harm" anything else than the application where you enable it (in the xsp.properties). So no eval magic at all - only things that happens on purpose!

Comment: The concept that it is only active when enabled in the xsp.properties is a good way to look at this.  I'm in the process of writing up a proposal for the installation, why it will be of benefit and how I can prove the code has not been hacked and will not cause harm..... fun.